# CSS 3 flip effect on mouse enter

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to display content on mouse enter with a flip effect as shown in this sample site http://www.taboola.com/

When you hover to the Drive Traffic section a blue colored div is flipped over. How can I do this with CSS3?

Comment: No, I didn't tried as I don't have much idea

Comment: You should try doing this on your own and then ask for help if you think you are stuck. But if you don't know how to start, maybe reading basics of CSS and HTML will be a good beginning in your journey. http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/htmlcss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right there in the code. Use your browser's inspection tools to find the relevant code per element. Here on StackOverflow we normally don't give freebies, i.e. we expect you to do some effort and not simply come here asking for this or that. Now that you know this, [I extracted the relevant code from the source code](http://jsfiddle.net/uevno1jc/). It's up to you to make it fit your needs.

```
.cta3 li {
  perspective: 1000;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 33.3%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.cta3 li .cta3 {
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: 400ms;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #3570CC;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2000;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.cta3 li:hover .cta3 {
  bottom: -10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me and I got the instructions to post answers here :-)